# Why are comment response notifications limited to one user name?

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, display-names, comment-replies

There are times where multiple users commented to a question I posted. Most had very useful information or suggestions and I wish to thank them all at once or ask them all the same question that is applicable to all. Why are comment responses limited to one @named user? Please consider changing this so that all those who commented can be notified of a response that applies to all.

Comment: @Glorfindel I did do a search and did not find my answer. However you are right. It is a near duplicate of the link you shared which was originally posted 8 years, 6 months ago. But since it is a feature request is there a rule that states a feature cannot be requested again at a later time (almost 9 years later)? Is that not showing support for the feature which might influence change in policy especially if conditions no longer exist under which the original policy was set? Please consider that before marking a feature request as a duplicate. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the feature request. I sympathize, finding old questions is really hard on meta, you can literally get hundreds of results even if you use specific keywords.   Only users who have spent considerable time on meta seem to know where to look.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you. I did look and found nothing but I must admit that I did not do a typical deep search which I should have done. So it might be that most newbies as myself did not try hard enough in the beginning. This error on my part shall be used as a lesson learned.